# Python regex not greedy enough, multiple groups

Tags: python, regex

When trying to do some regexp matching in python, I stumbled over an oddity. I wanted to match decimal numbers on the form xxx.yyy and divide them into three groups for further processing. I ran something like the following snippet.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import re

matches = re.search("a=(\d+)(\.?)(\d+?)", "var k = 2;var a; a=46")
print(matches.group(1))
```

Print returns 4, whereas 46 would be the expected result. Why would that be? Python documentation states that the regexp + and * are greedy, but that does not seem to be the case here. The reason seems to be that the last digit ends up in the last group. I need to at least match the first and the last group. I could skip the middle group if i use the last to distinguish between decimal and non-decimal numbers.

It does however seem to work if the number matched is a decimal.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import re

matches = re.search("a=(\d+)(\.?)(\d+?)", "var k = 2;var a; a=46.3")
print(matches.group(1))
```

Prints 46. I would be delighted if you could help me solve this conundrum. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two groups of decimals, with at least 1 digit. So group 1 is `4` and group 2 is empty and group 3 is `6`. If you want to match all digits in front of the `.` to match, you have to make the second and third group optional:

```
matches = re.search("a=(\d+)(?:(\.?)(\d+))?", "var k = 2;var a; a=46")
```

Comment: Did some evaluation, and I believe this answer is closest to what I wanted to achieve. Thank you @Daniel.

Answer (score 2):

It should be

```
matches = re.search("a=(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)", "var k = 2;var a; a=46")
```

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/n8PARJ)**

**Reason**

Your regex is

```
(\d+)(\.?)(\d+?)
```

Your `.` is optional which means that your both `.` and the next `\d+?` are independent of each other.It means that it first matches all the digits (i.e. till `4` in your example) of your input till the next `.` which is optional and it requires at least one digit for the last group to succeed. So `6` will be in last captured group.

This picture will make more clear

[image]

Comment: @Racialz its from http://www.regex101.com/
after writing a regex, you can use the regex debugger mode (appears in left side) on that site